# How does /sys/class/pci_bus correlate the physical PCIe lanes?

Tags: pci, device-tree

On a Dell R7525 I see the following output:

```bsh
[root@r7525 ~]# ls -al /sys/class/pci_bus/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 0 May 10 10:38 .
drwxr-xr-x. 62 root root 0 May 10 10:38 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:00 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/pci_bus/0000:00
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:01 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/pci_bus/0000:01
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:02 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/pci_bus/0000:02
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:03 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/pci_bus/0000:03
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:04 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/pci_bus/0000:04
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:20 -> ../../devices/pci0000:20/pci_bus/0000:20
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:21 -> ../../devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:07.1/pci_bus/0000:21
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:22 -> ../../devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:08.1/pci_bus/0000:22
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:40 -> ../../devices/pci0000:40/pci_bus/0000:40
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:41 -> ../../devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:07.1/pci_bus/0000:41
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:42 -> ../../devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:08.1/pci_bus/0000:42
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:60 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/pci_bus/0000:60
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:61 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:05.2/pci_bus/0000:61
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:62 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:05.2/0000:61:00.0/pci_bus/0000:62
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:63 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.1/pci_bus/0000:63
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:64 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:07.1/pci_bus/0000:64
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:65 -> ../../devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:08.1/pci_bus/0000:65
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:80 -> ../../devices/pci0000:80/pci_bus/0000:80
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:81 -> ../../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:01.2/pci_bus/0000:81
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:82 -> ../../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:07.1/pci_bus/0000:82
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:83 -> ../../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:08.1/pci_bus/0000:83
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:a0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:a0/pci_bus/0000:a0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:a1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:a0/0000:a0:07.1/pci_bus/0000:a1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:a2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:a0/0000:a0:08.1/pci_bus/0000:a2
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:c0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:c0/pci_bus/0000:c0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:c1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:c0/0000:c0:01.1/pci_bus/0000:c1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:c2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:c0/0000:c0:07.1/pci_bus/0000:c2
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:c3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:c0/0000:c0:08.1/pci_bus/0000:c3
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:c4 -> ../../devices/pci0000:c0/0000:c0:08.3/pci_bus/0000:c4
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:e0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:e0/pci_bus/0000:e0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:e1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:e0/0000:e0:05.1/pci_bus/0000:e1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:e2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:e0/0000:e0:07.1/pci_bus/0000:e2
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 May 10 10:38 0000:e3 -> ../../devices/pci0000:e0/0000:e0:08.1/pci_bus/0000:e3
```

I know in this server there are 64 lanes per proc available for public consumption plus some are dedicated to things like the OCP and iDRAC. Since this is a dual-proc system, we know there are two separate root complexes but that AMD has worked its magic to make the two separate root complexes present as a range of non-overlapping bus IDs which is why when I do `lspci -D` I see a single PCIe domain listed rather than two.

My question is that I haven't been able to work out how what I see here in /sys/class/pci_bus maps back to those physical lanes. There appear to be 33 addresses listed here and that these addresses are mapped by `domain:bus:slot.function`. I don't understand what this is saying though - ex: e3, which would be a bus, is decimal 227. There aren't that many buses. What is the correlation between these bus numbers and the physical buses on the server?